# Copying across embedded HTML links using Safari

Tags: safari

I have recently upgraded from a Mac mini to an iMac (and love it!). On the Mac mini I used Firefox but on the iMac I am starting out with Safari.

I publish a blog with a new post every day. Frequently, my daily post includes a copy of something that has been published on another blog and contains links to other sites beyond that.

However, when I copy and paste that content across to my own blog it does not automatically copy across the embedded html links that were in the original. Firefox did copy across those links.

Is there a setting in Safari that will change the way a copy is made so that those html links are included without any other keystrokes required from me?

Did that all make sense?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have seen Safari does not copy the URLs when you select text with URLs in them. However that may be more of a function of the destination. I say this because if you select text (pictures too) from a web page that has hyperlinks in it, paste it into an MS Office document and MS Word preserves all formatting, including hyperlinks, pictures and formatting *as it appeared on the source web page.*

So you may have to use Firefox on your new iMac to do that particular thing assuming you don't want to copy the source of the page just the intact URLs.